# Networkx Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP)

Tags: python, networkx, mathematical-optimization

I would like to know if there is a function in NetworkX to solve the TSP? I can not find it. Am I missing something? I know it's an NP hard problem but there should be some approximate solutions right?

Comment: @bottledatthesource Does this help? https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dwave-networkx/en/latest/reference/algorithms/tsp.html

Comment: @bottledatthesource TSP is not equivalent to finding all shortest paths (what Dijkstra does)

Comment: I see dwavesys implementation but I thought I wanted it straight from NetworkX. Anyhow my question really is which of the algorithms pertain to TSP (from a source to any target travel through all the nodes with shortest path weight). For example, these are very confusing: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html

Comment: @bottledatthesource networkx is a graph manipulation library, sort of a numpy for graphs. Problems like TSP are out of its scope

Comment: @marat TSP is really different from finding all shortest path, finding all shortest is in P while TSP is NP-hard. ANd TSP is not out of the scoop of Netwokx, in Networkx several algorithms are implemented, e.g. djikstra, kruskal, ford-bellman...

Comment: @hola the comment about Dijkstra was a response to another comment by bottledatthesource and might look confusing now. Your answer points to an extension package `dwave_networkx` and not `networkx` itself, so I guess the point about nx scope still holds.

Comment: @Marat the fact that this function is dwave_networkx doesn't change the fact that this problem is in the scope of Networkx, the other examples, .i.e. Djikstra, Kruskal, Ford-Bellman,  I mentioned are all implemented in networkx

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77418170/edit)

Answer (score 4):

Networkx provides an approximate solution to TSP, see [page](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dwave-networkx/en/latest/reference/algorithms/tsp.html). Their solution is based on writting TSP as Quadratic Unconstrained Binary Optimization (QUBO) problem.

Note that it is proven that finding an alpha-approximation to TSP is proven to be NP-hard in general. So you can't have a guarantee on the quality the obtained result. Howver there is a particular case, Euclidean-TSP, where we can construct 2-approximation and even 1.5-approximation of TSP, using [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) however I was not able to find the implementation of this algorithm in Networkx.

Comment: Note that the link to the TSP solution is from a 3rd-party package named `dwave_networkx` and is not part of networkx core.

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of networkx include some algorithms for approximating or brute-forcing solutions to the tsp: see [the docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/approximation.html#module-networkx.algorithms.approximation.traveling_salesman) for some examples.