# I want to convert a matrix of nodes and distances into a table with columns for node1, node2 and the distance between them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I am working with csv file that contains a header with each node and a corresponding row with each node, with each data field corresponding to the difference between the two nodes like so:

| Blank | 4 | 38 | 71 | 90 | 94 | ... | 8545 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 1280 | 1762 | 1406 | 1589 | ... | 1017 |
| 38 | 1280 | 0 | 681 | 202 | 385 | ... | 1433 |
| 71 | 1762 | 681 | 0 | 503 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 90 | 1406 | 202 | 503 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1559 |
| 94 | 1589 | 385 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1742 |
| .. | .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | 0 | ... |
| 8545 | 1017 | 1433 | 0 | 1559 | 1742 | ... | 0 |

(in this context 0 means there is no connection, either because they are the same node or they are not joined)

I would like to change the layout so it instead resembles this:

| Node1 | Node2 | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 4 | 38 | 1280 |
| 4 | 71 | 1762 |

And so on, including all nodes and their connections

Is there a pythonic way to carry this out?

Comment: If you are interested to perform graph operations on your data, as you current task is the transformation of an adjacency matrix to a edge list, I would also recommend that you take a look at [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) package. Say if you want to go that way, then I would add an answer using [networkx pandas write/read](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html#pandas) methods.

Comment: Yes I'm looking to use this data later on to solve a version of the TSP with multiple start nodes so I would appreciate that style of answer very much.

Comment: Yatu already wrote an answer including creation of networkx graph - for TSP I also found another question probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887217/networkx-traveling-salesman-problem-tsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most graph operations, you'll find huge advantages if you work with graph libraries. In this case, you can easily create a graph from the dataframe and add those distances as [edge weights](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEdge.html#:%7E:text=For%20an%20undirected%20graph%2C%20an,an%20ordered%20pair%20of%20nodes.).

Then for the desired output you'd just need to retrieve the graph edge's weights in this case, which can be easily done using [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) with:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
print(weights)
{(94, 4): 1589,
 (94, 38): 385,
 (4, 38): 1280,
 (4, 71): 1762,
 (4, 90): 1406,
 (38, 71): 681,
 (38, 90): 202,
 (71, 90): 503}
```

Or if you want the result as a dataframe:

```
(pd.DataFrame(weights.keys(), columns=['node1', 'node2'])
    .assign(Distance=weights.values()))

   node1  node2  Distance
0     94      4      1589
1     94     38       385
2      4     38      1280
3      4     71      1762
4      4     90      1406
5     38     71       681
6     38     90       202
7     71     90       503
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) here for better perfomance like `pd.concat` with list comprehension:

```
df2 = df.stack().rename_axis(['Node1','Node2']).reset_index(name='Distance')
print (df2.head(15))
    Node1 Node2  Distance
0       4     4         0
1       4    38      1280
2       4    71      1762
3       4    90      1406
4       4    94      1589
5       4  8545      1017
6      38     4      1280
7      38    38         0
8      38    71       681
9      38    90       202
10     38    94       385
11     38  8545      1433
12     71     4      1762
13     71    38       681
14     71    71         0
```

Another idea is use numpy:

```
c = np.tile(df.columns, len(df))
i = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns))
v = np.ravel(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Node1':i, 'Node2':c, 'Distance':v})
```

**Performance**:

```
#6k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
# print(df)

In [37]: %timeit df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Node1':np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns)), 'Node2':np.tile(df.columns, len(df)), 'Distance':np.ravel(df)})
1.77 ms ± 42.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit df.stack().rename_axis(['Node1','Node2']).reset_index(name='Distance')
4.39 ms ± 475 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[i, j, df.at[i, j]]], columns=['Node1', 'Node2', 'Distance']) for i in df.index   for j in df.columns], ignore_index=True)
31.6 s ± 1.22 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Is the numpy sensitive for ordering/completeness of elements? That is good to know if so. Nice overview

Comment: @user3184950 - yes, also is possible use parameter order in [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) if need different order

Answer (score 1):

What I would to, is use Pandas [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.abs(1 - np.corrcoef( np.random.random( size=(8,8) ))) * 100
```

A is just to have some random more or less similar data.

We now create a df with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns = [ "node_" + str(i) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
```

```
         node_0      node_1      node_2      node_3      node_4      node_5  \
0  1.110223e-14  177.640823   94.528739  102.894884   75.716800   16.959874   
1  1.776408e+02    0.000000  100.594166   69.032398  106.857164  180.845071   
2  9.452874e+01  100.594166    0.000000  143.128873  154.447302  114.711230   
3  1.028949e+02   69.032398  143.128873    0.000000   25.162778  129.170641   
4  7.571680e+01  106.857164  154.447302   25.162778    0.000000   74.135700   
5  1.695987e+01  180.845071  114.711230  129.170641   74.135700    0.000000   
6  1.424585e+02   74.925019   70.156519   70.914395  125.433304  171.546764   
7  8.862326e+01   67.220779  139.488270   61.680713   58.115007   98.620041
```

and you can `df.stack()`

```
df_stacked = df.stack()
```

You can make it a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame( df_stacked )`

Comment: OP is asking for the distance (same value as in original df), not the correlation coefficient

Comment: Indeed. It is just some data to play with, with similar diagonal.